# Why doesn't gcloud app deploy include my custom made module?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, node-modules

In my Node application script I require a custom made module which has its own dependencies. In local development this all works fine and everything works as expected. However, when I want to deploy my application as a whole through gcloud app deploy the following error occurs:

```
Updating service [myapp]...failed.                                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:

> myapp@1.0.0 start /app
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mycustommodule'
```

Does this have anything to do with that maybe gcloud tries to download all node modules for itself from the NPM server and therefore obviously can't find my local module? I can't figure out how to include my own node modules (that also have their own dependencies).

I thank you for thinking along with me in advance.
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the `gcloud app deploy` command, the SDK automatically creates a `.gcloudignore` file that pretty much works like `.gitignore` and filters out some files or directories that won't be deployed.

`.gcloudignore` by defaults include the `node_modules/` directory so your installed dependencies aren't uploaded alongside your code. You can remove this entry from the .gcloudignore and try to deploy again.

Comment: Hmm, I did not know that. I am going to try it out as soon as I get the chance to (plus do the stackoverflow reward thing). If I understand correctly I need to deploy with the --ignore-file=[file] flag pointing to an empty .gcloudignore file which will overwrite the one that gets generated automatically?

Comment: You can do it that way yes. Or, if you already ran gcloud app deploy, edit the .gcloudignore file to remove the node_modules folder.

Comment: Where/how should I be able to see if such a file already exists?

Comment: You should be able to see it running ls -al in the folder from where you run gcloud app deploy. If it doesn't exist, you can just create it yourself (don't forget the dot)